# Unknown column in 'on clause' MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Unknown column 'a.date_quotation' in 'on clause' 
Can anybody help me, how to access the fields of the table `a` to be used in the condition clause on another table (b, c)? please see the picture

[image]

Comment: You can't use a.date_quotation in your inner query since it's not available there.

Comment: it's can't acsess from other subquery ?

Comment: Not in the FROM section, only in the WHERE section

Answer (score 0):

You should either move the conditions on fields from "a" to an outer where clause or include "a" as a part of the inner join when coming up with "b" and "c".